# Auto save login user_id as a foreignkey using forrm.py in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

`how to  submit form which automatically take user_id of current active user as a Foreignkey  with form.py file in django

form.py:

```
from django import forms 
from .models import BBB
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class AdminBModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = BBB
    fields = ['id','content','user_id']
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class BBB(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bs', 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import BBB
from . forms import AdminBModelForm
from django.http import HttpResponse 
# Create your views here.
def index(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = AdminBModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save() 
            return redirect('success') 
    else: 
        form = AdminBModelForm() 
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form' : form}) 

def success(request): 
    return HttpResponse('successfully uploaded') \
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        {% csrf_token %} 
        {{ form.content }} 
        <button type="submit">Upload</button> 
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

This form only takes one field content and autosave user login id

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: AKX thanks for your time I upload code I hope now you understand my question

Answer (score 0):

Before `form.save()`, do `form.instance.user_id = request.user`.

As an aside, it'd be a good idea to rename that field to just `user` instead of `user_id`.